# An example of $_AM$ is simple but $M^\star_A$ is not?

Tags: modules, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$ algebra, $k$ is a field. It is evident that the duality functor ($(-)^\star=hom_k(-,k)$)  preserves the simplicity in the case of finitely generated  $A$- modules (left $A$-modules  to right $A$- modules ) [here is a proof in a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/400173/60099)

My question is, could you possibly  provide me with a counterexample of the infinite dimensional case. That is $_AM$ is simple but $M^\star_A$ is not, where $A$ is still finite dimensional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra, then **every** simple $A$-module is finite dimensional, since it is a quotient of the regular module (if $S$ is a simple left module, then for any $0\neq s\in S$, $a\mapsto as$ is a non-zero homomorphism $A\to S$, which is surjective since $S$ is simple).

Comment: That is right, thank you,  so if I edit my question and change it to indecomposable module, or remove the condition on $A$, would my question make sense? The purpose of my question is to see where this functor does not preserve simplicity or indecomposability.  But I thought it makes sense if I asked that way (and you showed that it does not ).

Comment: @math137 Yes, for indecomposable modules it makes sense, and the dual may not be indecomposable. One way to see this is that for any infinite dimensional module, the natural map $M\to M^{\star\star}$ to the double dual is injective but not surjective, and splits if $M$ is itself the dual of some module, so in that case $M^{\star\star}$ can't be indecomposable. So if $A$ has any infinite dimensional indecomposable module $M$, then either $M$ or $M^{\star}$ is indecomposable with a decomposable dual (depending on whether or not $M^\star$ is decomposable).

Comment: Could you please tell me where can I read about these facts?

Comment: @math137 I'm not sure exactly which aspects you're interested in, or how much you know already, but you might be interested in the notes https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/pure/staff/crawley_b/infdim2.pdf by Crawley-Boevey. He gives some examples using representations of the Kronecker quiver: in particular, the first example in section 1.3 is an indecomposable module whose dual is decomposable.

Comment: These are nice notes thank you. With respect to the background I felt  ok when I saw the notes, and I am a beginner in this area. My interest is finite dimensional associative algebras.